# Google Chrome rejects SSL certificate with NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Trying to build SSL web-site in my local network and access it by IP. I made certificate for 192.168.0.x and signed it with self-made CA certificate. Signed certificate was installed on my web-server, and public CA certificate was installed on my certificate storage ("trusted CA" section). Now IE opens my site, but Chrome shows NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error. What issue can cause this?

Comment: While your question is missing details like how exactly the certificate looks like and what the full error message is my guess is that you've just added the IP address as common name - which was wrong and is no longer accepted by Chrome. See the question about subject alternative name missing for more details. If you don't feel that this is a duplicate please add enough details to your question to make it clear that this is a different problem.

Comment: The 2 questions referred to do not resolve the problem of NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID with self-signed root certificates.